# Time complexity of getting the number of subarrays of an array that satisfies a certain condition

Tags: algorithm

What is the optimal time complexity of getting the number of subarrays of an array that satisfies a certain condition. For example, [24, 36, 21, 56, 3, 9, 75], we attempt to get the number of subarrays that the summation is greater than the summation of values outside the subarray.

Comment: It entirely depends on how easy the condition is to reason about. If all values are non-negative, your example can be done in time `O(n)`. If you have negative values then I don't see how to do it in time better than `O(n log(n))`.

Comment: I agree with btilly because time complexity depend on how many steps are you performing to complete that task so it directly depend on your condition and input. in your case condition is "summation is greater than the summation of values outside the subarray" and array is [24, 36, 21, 56, 3, 9, 75] so `O(n)`